# Shortest path finding for multiple points in 2d ware house

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

[2d ware house layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3qrx.png)
in 2d layout task is to find shortest distance for getting material from storage points
Z00 ,Z01 .... may be start or end points based on user input
A1A1 B1A1 ....are storage points
Only horizontal and vertical movement is allowed ( NO diagonal movement to reach storage points)
Assuming distance between each block is 1 (one ) meter
Task is to find shortest distance Start from Z00 visit A1A1 , C1A4 and end at Z02

I am using networkx.  Not able to find correct layout for visuals of layout and distance for multiple visit points also

Comment: 1- is this a real-life issue or homework? 2- please provide a [mre] of your input data, an image is not reproducible. Make sure to provide the expected output for a few representative examples. 3- clarify the logic: how can one move exactly? Is a direct A1A3->B1A3 move allowed? Explain all rules in detail. 4- where is the code of your own attempt?

Comment: This is real life issue

Comment: This is real life isuue  . In excel 2d layout looks like 
      
Y codrinate       
      
5 Z10               Z11  
4  A1B1 B1B1   
3  A1B2 B1B2   
2  A1B3 B1B3   
1  A1B4 B1B4   
0 Z20               Z21  
 0 1 2 3           X cordinate

Z20 ,Z10,Z11 ,Z21 May be start or end points 

Constraints - Only x ad y direction movement is allowed No diagonal movement 
For 
For example 
Start point is Z20, End point is Z11 Visiting point is A1B3 and B1B2 
Possible way to fins shortest path is 
Z20 --A1B3--A1B1--A1B1--B1B1--B1B2 --Z11 
Z20--A1B3--A1B4--B1B4--B1B2--Z11

Comment: Please [edit] the question with this information. Make sure that it is easily reusable.